# How to stop DispatcherTimer in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

I am checking the time and when is equal to something I want to stop the dispatcher.

But it doesn't work. Timer is still working after calling `Stop()`.

```
private void startTime(bool what)
{
    vartimer = new DispatcherTimer();

    if (!what)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Start");

        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timer.Tick += setTime;
        timer.Start();
    }

    if (what)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Stop");
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

When it starts, it is showing the Start text. When it should stop, it should show the Stop text but it is still working.

Did I do something wrong?

```
timer.stop();
```

Should stop the `Dispatcher`, right?

Comment: How many events do you get if stop was called? may be try to first stop then show the message box so it is already stopped when the box shows up.

Comment: FYI, Dispatcher and DispatcherTimer are different classes, and they are not interchangeable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define the `DispacherTimer` *outside* your method:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
private void startTime(bool what)
{
    if (what == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Start");

        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timer.Tick -= setTime;
        timer.Tick += setTime;
        timer.Start();
    }

    if (what == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Stop");
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

In your current code, you are creating a new instance of the `DispacherTimer` each time the method is called.

Comment: Thanks... And again i have to learn a lot ;) You have right. I always create new instance when i call the method like you said. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Your instance of `DispatcherTimer` should be a private field of your class because everytime you are calling `startTime(...)`, you are creating a new instance of the `DispatcherTimer` class that is started but never stopped. Here is an example of what could be done:

```
public class YourClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer m_timer;

    public YourClass()
    {
          m_timer = new DispatcherTimer();
          m_timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
          m_timer.Tick += setTime;            
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
          m_timer.Tick -= setTime;    
          m_timer.Stop(); 
    }

    private void startTime(bool what)
    {
        if(what == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Start");

            m_timer.Start();
        }

        if(what == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Stop");

            m_timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

I also added the `IDisposable` implementation to make sure the `Dispatcher` instance is properly unsubscribed from and stopped.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class A
{
  private DispatcherTimer _timer; // This is a global variable
  public void StartTime(bool what)
  {
   DispatcherTimer timer = new Dispatcher(); //This is a local variable
   ...
  }
}
```

When you call the StartTime function，the timer is a new instance. If you run StartTime(false) and StartTime(true), it will have two DispatcherTimer;